# removing all text nodes from a particular div tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, textnode

i have some dynamically generated html from a php script. the php code looks like this

```
echo "<div id='categories'>\n";
foreach($category as $k => $v)
{
echo "<div class='category'>\n";
echo "<div id=\"$k\" class='cat_name'\n>$k</div>\n";
echo "<div id=\"$k".'_link"'." class='cat_link'>\n<a href=$v>Link</a>\n</div>\n";
echo "</div>\n";
}
echo "</div>\n";
```

i have a javascript file that tries to access the dom like this

```
var categories=document.getElementById('categories').childNodes;
for(i=0;i<categories.length;i++)
{
var link=categories[i].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].attributes['href'];
..
...
..
```

now this doesnt work as expected because there are text nodes in the html.
when i used the `firebug console` to try this

```
document.getElementById('categories').childNodes[0].nodeType; // displays 3
```

it displays `3` which means that the node is a `text node`.
i tried adding `document.normalize();` in `window.onload` like this

```
window.onload=function() {
document.normalize();
var categories=document.getElementById('categories').childNodes;
...
...
```

but the text nodes remain in the html. how can i remove all the text nodes. now i dont think there is any method like `getElementByType()` so how do i get all text nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.children` instead of `.childNodes` to target elements only (no text nodes):

```
   // --------------------------------------------------v
var categories=document.getElementById('categories').children;
```

FF3 doesn't support that property, so if you're supporting that browser, you'll need a method to replicate it.

```
function children( parent ) {
    var node = parent.firstChild;
    var result = [];
    if( node ) {
        do {
            if( node.nodeType === 1 ) {
                result.push( node );
            }
        } while( node = node.nextSibling )
    }
    return result;
}
var parent = document.getElementById('categories');
var categories= parent.children || children( parent );
```

Also note that IE will give you comment nodes as well, so it would be better if your markup didn't include comments.

Answer (score 4):

### EE2015 syntax:

```js
var elm = document.querySelector('ul');

console.log(elm.outerHTML);

// remove all text nodes
[...this.elm.childNodes].forEach(elm => elm.nodeType != 1 && elm.parentNode.removeChild(elm))

console.log(elm.outerHTML);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  a
  <li>2</li>
  b
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

#### Breakdown:

1. Get **all** children
2. Convert the HTMLCollection to an Array
3. Traversing the Array and checking each item if it's of type *text node*
4. If so, remove the item from the DOM

*This will only remove direct-child text nodes and nothing deeper in the tree.*

---

### with [NodeIterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeIterator):

```js
var elm = document.querySelector('ul')

// print HTML BEFORE removing text nodes
console.log(elm.outerHTML)

// remove all text nodes
var iter = document.createNodeIterator(elm, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT)
var node;
while (node = iter.nextNode()) {
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node)
}

// print HTML AFTER removing text nodes
console.log(elm.outerHTML)
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3<span>4</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [`getElementsByClassName` <sup>MDC docs</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) instead ?

```
var categories=document.getElementByClassName('category');
```

For browsers that do not natively support it look at these implementations : http://ejohn.org/blog/getelementsbyclassname-speed-comparison/

Comment: that doesnt solve my problem.there are text nodes all over my html. i need to remove those text nodes for further traversal

Comment: @lovesh, then you should use the [answer of patrick dw](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472464/removing-all-text-nodes-from-a-particular-div-tag-using-javascript/6472637#6472637)

Answer (score 0):

Check each node in your loop and if it's a text node, then either remove it as you said or do nothing. If it's not a text node, do what action you want to do to it.